# C#.Net Web Application with Html Javascript when first page loading data from database second page not responding

Tags: javascript, c#

I have a c#.net web application which uses html and javascript. When I open the browser and load a page, it goes and gets data from database through .cs controller and that process takes about 45 seconds to complete. Meanwhile if I open another tab in the chrome browser and launch another page of the application, it does NOT respond until the first page finish processing. What should I do to have multiple tabs to run different pages while others are running?

Comment: Take a look at the Dev tools in the Browser and see what the network tab has. Also post some code from the controller, might help find a leak?

Comment: Is this a deployed application on a web server, or localhost?

Comment: Without any code the best guess is that you might have some concurrency issues at the server. If for example you are running your request on SQLEXPRESS it is limited to one CPU. So if the first request takes 45 seconds to complete then the second one will not start until the first has completed

Comment: It sounds like you are encountering a Session lock.  Are you using SessionState at all in this controller?  You could try marking the page that takes 45 seconds to complete as using readonly sessionstate if you aren't writing to session in that action and see if it helps the problem.  You can do that by putting this on the controller: [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]